# Wireless not working only when using Fedora

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora

I just bought a new Asus laptop (ASUS F551CA)  that came with preinstalled Windows 8. I quickly installed Fedora 20 to the then empty D:-drive. Everything looks good: the dualboot process works fine. However, I am unable to connect to the internet using Fedora. (It works just fine in Windows.) It simply says "Hardware disabled." at the settings, and I am unable to do anything about it. Ethernet works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1680444&postcount=3

> I had the same problem in F20 with Asus X550C, which uses the
>   asus_nb_wmi module. The hardware switch is a bit flaky, as the led
>   isn't lit up even if wifi is active. Anyway, solution for me is as
>   follows:
>
> - As root, create a file named e.g. asus-wifi.conf and put it in in /etc/modprobe.d/
> - Insert this line in it: options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1
> - Reboot and see if wifi works.
>
> Works for me just fine, although it doesn't fix the wifi switching
>   with Fn+F2, but that's not a problem for me. More info and where I got
>   the fix from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558
>
> Possibly just blacklisting the module can work too, as some people
>   reported, but I haven't tried.

Comment: I will attempt that and report back momentarily, hopefully from my Fedora install.

Comment: I hope it works. if didn't, check these two links too : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/wifi-setup-on-fedora-17-a-949088/  and  http://www.itshacked.com/293/wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-broadcom-wlan-drivers-ubuntu-fedora-opensues.html

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! On an unrelated note, have you noted any instability with the network using Asus computers? In noobtalk, I barely get one bar, and the network is often unstable. I just recently updated my network driver.

Comment: your welcome :) glad it works.

Comment: Plagiarized from https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1680444&postcount=3